# How To Organize My Desk

Tags: organization

When I clear my desk up, a few days later it is messy again. It is big but I have many things that I forget to clean up after using them. 
I tried a few things:

- Having a little reminder
- Each object having it's own place
- Using a tray with a few parts for different materials

My desk is still very messy.

Comment: As you presented this, this is an extraordinarily broad question — I think folks can only *guess* at what solutions might help you specifically. I suggest getting way more focused on a specific organizational problem that can be resolved definitively in the space of a post; unfortunately, this type of cleanup system or organizational strategy is a better fit for our **[Personal Productivity site](https://productivity.stackexchange.com)**. Good luck!